# Error when creating new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a new user from my form in my new.html.erb file:

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign Up"%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In my users_controller.rb I have this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "Sign Up"
    @user = Users.new
  end
```

And I have this in my routes.rb

```
resources :users
```

I keep getting an error: http://d.pr/wJm8 when I go to users/new and I can't figure out what's wrong...help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some plurality inconsistencies. Your model should be named `User` not `Users`.

Comment: Ok, I used `User` but then I get the error `uninitialized constant UsersController::User`

Comment: You renamed your model as well? Depending on the situation you may have to redo your migration/scaffolding. It's hard to say without having the entire context. Worst case you copy your current user view/model/controller to an outside directory, delete all your current user stuff, roll back the migration and start over, pulling in bits of the old code as you build it back up.

Comment: My model is named users.rb `class Users < ActiveRecord::Base` Would this be a problem with my routes?

Comment: Oh I believe my model needs to be named User instead, crap

Comment: Yes; you want to name your model class User, not Users.